# Install Solaris Studio failed

Tags: solaris, solaris-studio

ALL,

I successfully installed Oracle Solaris on the VirtualBox as a gues, then updated it and installed the vbox guest additions.

Now I'm trying to install Solaris Studio there:

```
root@solaris:~# beadm list
BE        Active Mountpoint Space   Policy Created          
--        ------ ---------- -----   ------ -------          
solaris   -      -          182.00M static 2018-08-14 19:31 
solaris-1 NR     /          6.13G   static 2018-08-14 23:06 
root@solaris:~# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                             TYPE     STATUS   URI
solaris                               origin   online   http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
root@solaris:~# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                             TYPE     STATUS   URI
solaris                               origin   online   http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
root@solaris:~# pkg list sunpro-incorporation
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.174.0.0.0.0.0     i--
root@solaris:~# pkg list -af sunpro-incorporation
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.175.3.20.0.2.0    ---
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.175.3.9.0.2.0     ---
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.25.0    ---
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.175.2.1.0.4.0     ---
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.175.2.0.0.37.0    ---
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.19.0    ---
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.174.0.0.0.0.0     i--
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.151.0.1           ---
root@solaris:~# pkg update -nv --accept
WARNING: pkg(5) appears to be out of date, and should be updated before
running update.  Please update pkg(5) by executing 'pkg install
pkg:/package/pkg' as a privileged user and then retry the update.
root@solaris:~# pkg install pkg:/package/pkg
pkg: The image cannot be modified as it is currently in use by another   package client: updatemanager on solaris, pid 1516.
root@solaris:~#
```

How do I fix it?

TIA!

Comment: This is likely more appropriate on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ as it's more related to system administration than programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AndrewHenle, agreed. Do you want me to close it/delete it?

Comment: Perhaps flag it so a moderator can address it?  The question being here is still a good signpost to the correct forum.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, done, thx.